# How to use browser libraries such as jquery, three.js and processing.js on browserify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, processing, browserify

Is it possible to use libraries such as jquery.js, processing.js and three.js on browserify, so I can completely stop using HTML  to require my client libs?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I'm asking if there's a generic way to do so, so if I find an obscure browser-targeting library that has not been ported to NPM I can still use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

However to work correctly with browserify libraries need to be done browserify style.  The good news it's not hard to convert, for most libraries it's mostly just a matter of getting their `module.exports` set up instead of exporting to `window`. And for many modules you don't need to do it your self since they're already published in browserify style on npm.  jQuery and three are in npm ready for browserify use.

Take a look here so see an example conversion: https://github.com/spine/jqueryify/blob/master/index.js#L8730-L8757

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim .

It allows using javascript files not compatible with commonJS modules in Browserify.

They have a specific example for jQuery: https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/tree/master/examples/shim-jquery .

If you are using grunt, [grunt-browserify](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-browserify) supports browserify-shim as well.